# How to obtain reports from NetSuite?

Tags: javascript, java, report, netsuite, suitescript

Hello friends I am working with NetSuite and SuiteScript. I'm pretty novice at this. I need to get a report that is in NetSuite to consume from an external application, you can do this with SuiteScript? or otherwise ?. I also tried to do with emulating HtmlUnit navigation on the page but when they log have the problem of not achieving additional authentication and saltarmela or to complete it with HtmlUnit.
Online reading I found that you can get a Web Query Excel, allowing this in the report options, but the reports I need to bring this option does not appear (in other reports that are in the account if, but right where I need not ). If puediesesn help of grateful.

Greetings!

Comment: what sort of report do you want to pull ?

Comment: As it is something that was done when I was assigned this project I have the certainty that type of report is, but upon entering the section to customize says "Financial Report Builder" therefore I assume that the report is financial. Of course thanks for the help. Greetings! @Rockstar

Answer (score 1):

Chris, you mention being able to consume NetSuite data inside of another application like Excel so based on that I have a few general recommendations.

There are more than a few ways to get data from NetSuite using external applications. Here are a few of the more common ways. Oh to answer your question about whether you can use SuiteScript - I think the answer is NO because SuiteScript is used inside NetSuite. SuiteScript is the code you use to customize NetSuite and SuiteScript is vanilla JavaScript that runs on the server & client.

1. Use NetSuite web services to pull data into a reporting application, .NET program or excel. Here is the [most recent WSDL file directly from NetSuite](https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2015_2_0/netsuite.wsdl) for the SOAP web services.
2. Use the NetSuite ODBC Driver or the NetSuite ADO.NET Driver. With these you can connect to NetSuite like you connect to a database. You can construct queries like any other SQL database, NetSuite is built on Oracle so many of the built in Oracle functions can be used such as decode.
3. Write a .NET, Java or PHP program that uses the NetSuite API and/or web services.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Although you can use RESTlets to pull data.